# How does goal-tracking and sign-tracking behaviour vary across species?

Tags: animal-cognition, behaviorism, reinforcement-learning, conditioning

In Pavlonian (classical) conditioning,  conditioned responses of an animal may vary. Some animals focus on the unconditioned stimulus (ie. food/location of food) while others may focus on the conditioned stimulus (ie. lever or button). These behaviors have been termed 'goal-tracking' and 'sign-tracking' respectively, as defined by Flagel et al. (2007).

- What are some known examples of this variation between different species?
- How does the variation within a species differ across species? Do some species exhibit more or less variation than other species?

<sub>Flagel SB, Watson SJ, Robinson TE, Akil H. (2007). [Individual differences in the propensity to approach signals vs goals promote different adaptations in the dopamine system of rats.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16972103) Psychopharmacology, Vol. 191, No. 3. (April 2007), pp. 599-607, doi:10.1007/s00213-006-0535-8 ([free PDF](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/terryrobinson/files/flagel_07.pdf))</sub>

Comment: Your question title is sorta asking two questions (examples + variance) but your question body only asks about variance; are you only interested in variation within/across species?

Comment: @BenBrocka In each species there is some variation. What I am interested in is how that variation itself differs between different species. I have a bit of trouble wording that, but hope it makes sense.